# SQL for compare three tables and list records unique to one table

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

Three stores purchase items over the year recorded in three Mysql tables. Is there a simple SQL statement to find out what items are purchased by a store which are not purchased by any of the other two? Only way I could do it by making multiple SQL statements and comparisons. Any help will be welcome.

Tables A, B, C - records List = A - (A.B.C) - (A.B) - (A.C)

Comment: Does each store have it's own table? Be more explicit about the tables and columns you have an issue with

Answer (score 0):

The syntax, especially concerning the concatenation, should definitely be wrong (no way for me to test) but you might try this concept:

`SELECT itemId From A Where itemId Not In (Select Concat(itemId,',') From B Union Select Concat(itemId,',') From C)
Union
SELECT itemId From B Where itemId Not In (Select Concat(itemId,',') From A Union Select Concat(itemId,',') From C)
Union
SELECT itemId From C Where itemId Not In (Select Concat(itemId,',') From B Union Select Concat(itemId,',') From A)`

Comment: Wrote pseudo code that actually runs, can't believe it :) Just tested it by iPhone which lasted half an hour but it worked - at least with integer type of itemId. Query (should be the same but verification is too hard work on mobile): `SELECT itemId From A Where itemId Not In (Select Concat(itemId,',') From B UNION SELECT CONCAT(itemId,',') From C)
union
SELECT itemId From B Where itemId Not In (Select Concat(itemId,',') From A UNION SELECT CONCAT(itemId,',') From C)
union
SELECT itemId From C Where itemId Not In (Select Concat(itemId,',') From B UNION SELECT CONCAT(itemId,',') From A)`